# Powershell script to login RDP session

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a .rdp file which is downloaded from azure cloud. I am wrote a script which will login to the machine and get some files. But the script is failing.

Can someone please guide me on this.
1). I will provide the machine name (.RDP file) in the script by providing the username & password.
2). Once the script runs, it has to collect the logs from C:\Windows\Logs\IE11_HardwareCheck.log and copy them to my local desktop (c:\windows\logs\machine_name) and change the file name with current date.

Thanks,
-Kalyan

Comment: RDP is for interactive use, you should look into [`PSRemoting`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/16/enable-powershell-remoting-to-enable-running-commands.aspx) instead

Comment: as long as they are on the same domain it would also be real easy to just do a `copy-file` unless there is some reason you need a .rdp file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. Actually this .RDP file which is downloaded from azure cloud.

Comment: If you can ping it, you can copy files from it.